# Ĉu okazis la KER-ekzameno por la nivelo A1?

Tags: ker-exams, certification

Suprizis min vidi ke laŭ la retejo de [edukado.net](http://edukado.net/ekzamenoj/ker/statistiko), iu diplomiĝis pri la nivelo A1 je la KER-ekzameno (ekzameno por lingvokonoj). A1 estas la plej baza nivelo, kaj mi ŝatus havi pli da informoj pri tio.

> Ĝis aprilo 2014 okazis 2 novaj ekzamensesioj, kaj tiel entute jam 39 en  29 landoj. Ĝis nun sukcese ekzameniĝis
>
> entute: 1800 personoj: **1 je A1**, 510 je B1, 543 je B2, 746 je C1-niveloj.

Mi ŝatus scii kie kaj kiam ĝi okazis.

Comment: Mi sxangxos tion en la demando, en kio mi uzas tion frazon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi ricevis respondon de la administranto de Edukado.net kiu informis min ke temas pri eraro kaj ŝi dankas vin pro la atentigo.

kore,

Axel